# Laravel - $request->input() is trimmed

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel with jquery ajax, when i send data using $.ajax and form serialize all data is sent to laravel controller (echo $request), but when i use (echo $request->input()) so of the data isn't there

ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    url: "/add_batch"
                }).done(function (data) 

                }).fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {

                });
```

LARAVEL function

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //return $request; //data is there
         return $request->input(); //data is missing
    }
```

note that the data is table rows, so when the rows numbers are low <100, everything is fine, after 110 rows no other rows are sent
any idea ?

Comment: What exactly are you missing? spaces on either end? string  becoming null? entire words missing?

Comment: add explanation, note that the data is table rows, so when the rows numbers are low <100, everything is fine, after 110 rows no other rows are returned although they are sent in network tab and returned in $request but not in input

Comment: can you do a `dd($request->all())` ?

Comment: @Quezler i get <script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump .... which make no sense compared to the $request itself

Comment: dd is a glorified interactive inspector, try opening it in a `preview` tab, some browsers have it

Comment: @Quezler [] empty array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171860/discussion-between-jenurudan-and-quezler).